# Cast light from one Object onto another Object

Tags: animation, rigging

I want the sun to glow and cast sunshine at the earth. I have set the surface of the sun to emission and 1000 in strength, but the earth is still in the dark when in rendered mode. Does anyone have a suggestion?

I am using Blender 2.8 and Cycles.

[image]

Comment: Which render engine are you using, Eevee? Then change it to Cycles!

Comment: I am using cycles render engine.

Comment: please show the node set of the earth material, it should be brighter...

Comment: Please don't crop the images you show so tight, show the interface. The effect you want might be there already but you just need to be in rendered view, not in material  or solid view. Show images of how you set the materials for both objects.

Answer (score 1):

In Cycles:

1. Set the desired Emission node value to your Sun-sphere;
2. Put, a bit in front of the Sun-sphere, the **spot** lamp lighting the Earth-sphere. The lamp's strength should match the emit value. And align the lamp with both spheres.

Done

Comment: Sorry! I am new to Blender and I don't know all its feature yet. What is a bit in Blender?